# How to return a custom http status code for SOAP faults

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, http-status-codes

I'm creating a WCF SOAP web service using BasicHttpBinding.

Unforunately, this service will be accessed through a firewall that does not allow returning http status code 500 replies from the server to the client. Any such messages from IIS are replaced with a generic error page generated by the firewall.

Therefore, my only option seems to be to return my faults disguised as http 200 messages. The consuming clients are still under development and pretty flexible, so that shouldn't be an issue. What is the best way to accomplish this? Code examples would be much appreciated.

They are doing something similar here, but my service won't be consumed by Silverlight:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ee844556(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: You already answered your own question. In the MSDN link nothing in the `SilverlightFaultBehavior` class is specific to Silverlight. Rename it and reuse it for you service.

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea if I was on the right track, so I wanted to be sure before trying to implement the Silverlight example. In the end, I did get it working using the example in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ErnieL wrote in his comment, [http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ee844556(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ee844556%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (Creating and Handling Faults in Silverlight) turned out to be a perfectly good example for my case. I renamed the "Silverlight" parts to "Firewall" to better reflect my specific case.